# why does an if statement shake the screen from side to side

Tags: java, android, if-statement, sudoku

In the hello android book there is a Sudoku solution. I wanted to create a message at the end that displays a dialog saying congratulations. I have a method to check if there are any empty squareds left and I call that in another method that checks if the last input was a valid entry for the square

```
/****** Check to see if the game is complete **/
public boolean isSolved() {
    for (int element : puzzle) {
        if (element == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/** Change the tile only if it's a valid move */
protected boolean setTileIfValid(int x, int y, int value) {
    int tiles[] = getUsedTiles(x, y);
    if (value != 0) {
        for (int tile : tiles) {
            if (tile == value)
                return false;
        }
    }
    setTile(x, y, value);
    calculateUsedTiles();
    //check if the game is complete after each valid move
            if (isSolved() == true) { 
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Congratulations.class); 
                startActivity(i);} 
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
    return true;
}
```

For some reason when i enter a tile before the game is complete the whole screen shakes from side to side. This did not do this before I entered the checking  of the game. Why and where is it doing this?

Congratulatons.xml
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/congratulations_text" />
   </ScrollView>`

Congratulations.java

```
package com.example.sudoku;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Congratulations extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.congratulations);
}
}
```

Comment: could you please post your <activity> tag from the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's some animation, responsible for shaking the screen.
It might be attached to the Congratulations Activity.

I think you need to search your code (especially the Congratulations Activity) for this method:

```
startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.shake));
```

Or it could be a theme (also custom theme) responsible for the animation in the activity tag of the AndroidManifest.xml

Maybe it's not the Congratulations Activity at all. It's probably the code part which is called, when the Sudoku was not solved yet.

Comment: Not that I am awear of. In the edit is the congratulations.xml and .java

Comment: Ok I have found it in a different class "PuzzleView" `public void setSelectedTile(int tile) {
  if (game.setTileIfValid(selX, selY, tile)) {
   invalidate();// may change hints
  } else {
   // Number is not valid for this tile
   Log.d(TAG, "setSelectedTile: invalid: " + tile);
   startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game, R.anim.shake));
  }
 }` How can I remove this so it does not shake?

Comment: read the code, slowly, line by line.  The comment  // Number is not valid for this tile answers your question.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to this so am doubting myself. I have completed a game with all the correct values in the tiles and every single input would shake the screen not just the incorrect values.

Comment: This was the case. There was a call to setSelectedTile which would show the number was invalid even when it was after calling my congratulations message. I ended up creating my own method to display the message which is what I should have done in the first place